# using different databses on same page

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

How can we access data from two different databases, on a same page using MEAN-stack? For example I want to give user Information and user watch history(both are different databases) on same page?

Answer (score 0):

you could just create multiple files for your separate mongoose connections.
for example in `db_one.js`:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_one');
module.exports = mongoose;
```

and then in `db_two.js`

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/db_two');
module.exports = mongoose;
```

and then import them in other Files as you wish